# Quaternion to RPY ROS2

Tags: ros, rclcpp, tf2, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ROS1 we had the possibility to calculate RPY-euler angles from quaternion using tf like this:

```
tf::Quaternion q(
        msg->pose.pose.orientation.x,
        msg->pose.pose.orientation.y,
        msg->pose.pose.orientation.z,
        msg->pose.pose.orientation.w);
    tf::Matrix3x3 m(q);
    double roll, pitch, yaw;
    m.getRPY(roll, pitch, yaw);
```

Is there any similar way to do it in ROS2? And if so which file do I have to include? I'm using ROS2-dashing in C++

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339528/quaternion-to-rpy-ros2/) by [LeoE](https://answers.ros.org/users/38438/leoe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 196 on 2019-12-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The big thing to note is that `tf` is not in ROS 2. You need to convert to `tf2` first. In tf2, that code would be identical (except for the namespace), however.

```
tf2::Quaternion q(
        msg->pose.pose.orientation.x,
        msg->pose.pose.orientation.y,
        msg->pose.pose.orientation.z,
        msg->pose.pose.orientation.w);
    tf2::Matrix3x3 m(q);
    double roll, pitch, yaw;
    m.getRPY(roll, pitch, yaw);
```

So, in short, just use tf2 instead of tf.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2019-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2